# "Gamification" gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Does anyone know of a "gamification" gem?  I'm looking for something that can provide the functionality that you would find from Badgeville, BigDoor, Bunchball, etc.  It seems like those platforms, outside of analytics and in some cases, a simple setup process for creating virtual rewards, don't offer a whole lot that you couldn't build yourself if all your need is a to create a simple event-based reward system.

If anyone knows of any gems, or plugins that provide a setup for adding virtual rewards and "gamification" to your Rails site, let me know!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I built a gem for managing rankings (levels), badges and points granting in Rails apps. It's hosted in https://github.com/tute/merit.

Comment: Does it work with Heroku?

Comment: Yes, but why wouldn't it?

Answer (score 14):

I've released my own open source gamification gem for RoR applications that uses Active Record, you should take a look, it's really easy to use, it's name is Gioco.

Here is the GitHub: https://github.com/GiocoApp/gioco
I have a post about it too: http://www.sitepoint.com/gioco-the-gamification-gem/

Gioco also has a SaaS version (http://gioco.pro) with client gem to setup into Rails applications and a Heroku Add-On to support it (http://addons.heroku.com/giocopro).

Answer (score 9):

Check out the UserInfuser (open source gamification platform) gem here: http://rubygems.org/gems/userinfuser

Comment: The documentation to this gem is super sparse.

Answer (score 2):

badgeable gem is fine, but there is also gem for BigDoor https://github.com/danieljohnmorris/big-door

Comment: @Splee and @merletta, thanks for your responses.  I'll check out BigDoor more closely, but what I was really after was something like 'Badgeable' that would allow me to create my own badging system.  Chances are I'll be back here after suffering through the development to let @splee say to me, "I told you so." :)

Answer (score 0):

Gamification is fairly new, so a generic gem probably isn't available right now (although I have not done exhaustive research into this as my main language is Python).

To build it yourself you'd probably need a fairly specific implementation for your framework/app.  Many people look at gamification platforms and think "that's easy, I could do that".  It's only once they start designing the system that they realize the complexity involved is much higher than it seems.

Using an API like [BigDoor](http://www.bigdoor.com)'s offers a way to cut development time and you get the benefit of improvements to the API from several publishers vs. feedback from a single implementation.

Using the gem which merletta linked might be a good starting point.

(DISCLAIMER: I am a developer at BigDoor)